# React Native - dropdown in a form with list loading dynamically

Tags: react-native, dropdown

In react native, I have a form (simple fields - name, address) and would like to add a dropdown to select user type. I would like to load the dropdown list dynamically from firebase. Is it possible ? Appreciate any help.

Updated:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {
         AppRegistry,
         StyleSheet,
         Text,
         View,
         Picker, 
   } from 'react-native';

   export default class Testpicker extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
            super(props);
           types = [{userType: 'admin', userName: 'Admin User'}, {userType:    'employee', userName: 'Employee User'}, {userType: 'dev', userName: 'Developer User'}];
this.setState({userTypes: types});        
 }


 loadUserTypes() {
    return this.state.userTypes.map(user => (
                                             <Picker.Item label={user.userName} value={user.userType} />
                                             ))
}

  render() {
       return (
        <View>
        <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedUserType}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
        this.setState({selectedUserType: itemValue})}>

        // Dynamically loads Picker.Values from this.state.userTypes.

        {this.loadUserTypes()}
        </Picker>

        </View>
          )
    }
   }

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Testpicker', () => Testpicker);
```

Now, I am getting an error message  "null is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.selectedUserType')."
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Edited my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can, imagine your data from firebase is like so.

`types = [{userType: 'admin', userName: 'Admin User'}, {userType: 'employee', userName: 'Employee User'}, {userType: 'dev', userName: 'Developer User'}]`

Save this data inside the state as `this.setState({userTypes: types});`

Create a function `loadUserTypes`in your class like so.

```
...
import {Picker} from 'react-native;
...
...

// Inside your class.

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // Use this.setState({userTypes: data}) when data comes from 
   // firebase. 
   this.state = {
     userTypes: [{userType: 'admin', userName: 'Admin User'}, {userType: 'employee', userName: 'Employee User'}, {userType: 'dev', userName: 'Developer User'}],
     selectedUserType: ''
   }
}


loadUserTypes() {
  return this.state.userTypes.map(user => (
     <Picker.Item label={user.userName} value={user.userType} />
  ))
}

// Then in your render.
render() {
 return (
  <View>
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.selectedUserType}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
          this.setState({selectedUserType: itemValue})}>

      // Dynamically loads Picker.Values from this.state.userTypes.

      {this.loadUserTypes()}
    </Picker>
  </View>
 )
}
```

`.map` function will transform each element of the `userTypes` array into a RN component that will be returned and we would have an array of RN components that we can render.

The documentation for `<Picker />` is available from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie. I used your code example and getting an error message "null is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.selectedUserType'). ". What am I doing wrong ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Oh. Really sorry, didn't know that. Going to edit the answer. I had intentionally skipped the constructor part since that was obvious. You have to define the state for being able to use it. Now you can use it, make sure you do `this.setState({userTypes: data})` with the firebase data if that's an array. Please make sure you also carefully study the data that comes from firebase and map it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I noticed that picker appears different in iOS and Android. Is there any dropdown that looks same in both platforms ?

Comment: Yes, I do have one. It's third party though. https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu